# Symmetrization of elastic constants based on rotational symmetry in Pymatgen

Tags: python, programming, pymatgen

I am trying to write a small python script which will symmetrize an elastic tensor based on rotational symmetry of the space group. I started with this [link](https://gist.github.com/terencezl/4e65b18c7ad76b9863940ebd8dc9fa32#user-content-fn-7-c9df14ee6bdfb5d27fd4c5b8dcfe9478) and created a new python script as below.

I started with cubic elastic constants in Voigt form and expected to get same results as input. But the final result shows C12=C14 which is not correct. **What might I be doing wrong?**

```
from pymatgen.core import Structure, Lattice
from pymatgen.symmetry.analyzer import SpacegroupAnalyzer
import numpy as np
from pymatgen.analysis.elasticity.elastic import ElasticTensor


structure = Structure.from_spacegroup(
    "Fm-3m", Lattice.cubic(1.0), ["element"], [[0, 0, 0]])
sga = SpacegroupAnalyzer(SpacegroupAnalyzer(structure).find_primitive())
ops_list = sga.get_symmetry_operations(cartesian=True)
ops_rotation_list = [op.rotation_matrix for op in ops_list]

C = np.array([[271.64, 141.6, 141.6,0,0,0],
              [141.6,271.64,141.6,0,0,0],
              [141.6,141.6,271.64,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,105.18,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,105.18,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,105.18]])
C_prime_sum = 0

CC = ElasticTensor(ElasticTensor.from_voigt(C).symmetrized)
for idx, op in enumerate(ops_rotation_list):
         # perform the 4th order tensor rotation.
        C_prime = ElasticTensor(
            np.einsum('im,jn,mnop,ok,pl', op, op, CC, op.T, op.T), tol=1e-5)
        C_prime_sum += C_prime
C_prime = C_prime_sum / (idx + 1)
A=C_prime.voigt
```

**Expected output** (Same as input matrix C)

```
C = np.array([[271.64, 141.6, 141.6,0,0,0],
              [141.6,271.64,141.6,0,0,0],
              [141.6,141.6,271.64,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,105.18,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,105.18,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,105.18]])
```

**current output** (Which is not correct)

```
[[271.64 117.32 117.32   0.     0.     0.  ]
 [117.32 271.64 117.32   0.     0.     0.  ]
 [117.32 117.32 271.64   0.     0.     0.  ]
 [  0.     0.     0.   117.32   0.     0.  ]
 [  0.     0.     0.     0.   117.32   0.  ]
 [  0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   117.32]]
```

Comment: +1. I was sorry to see that this Bounty didn't result in any answers. I did try to bump up the question to the top of the main page so that it could get more attention while the bounty was active. I've also posted a link to the question [here](https://gist.github.com/terencezl/4e65b18c7ad76b9863940ebd8dc9fa32?permalink_comment_id=4286119#gistcomment-4286119) but the author of that file seems to have moved away from working on science. Do you think you can show us the output that you get from running the script in your question, and say what you the *expected* output would be?

Comment: @NikeDattani I have updated question

Comment: @NikeDattani  I am now ready to answer this question. Is it possible to issue a bounty on this question again ? :P

Comment: @VandanRevanur second bounty will start from 100. I think if you answer correctly, we may give our old bounty of 50.@NikeDattani can give more details.

Comment: I will answer as soon as there is a bounty setup :)

Comment: @VandanRevanur I have started a bounty

Comment: @Pranavkumar Does my answer solve your question? If so could you please mark it as an accepted answer by clicking on the tick mark next to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

On Line 21 of your code, where you initialize the elastic tensor, if the `.symmetrized` part is removed, then you get the desired output.

#### Modified Code:

```
from pymatgen.core import Structure, Lattice
from pymatgen.symmetry.analyzer import SpacegroupAnalyzer
import numpy as np
from pymatgen.analysis.elasticity.elastic import ElasticTensor


structure = Structure.from_spacegroup(
    "Fm-3m", Lattice.cubic(1.0), ["element"], [[0, 0, 0]])
sga = SpacegroupAnalyzer(SpacegroupAnalyzer(structure).find_primitive())
ops_list = sga.get_symmetry_operations(cartesian=True)
ops_rotation_list = [op.rotation_matrix for op in ops_list]

C = np.array([[271.64, 141.6 , 141.6 ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
              [141.6 , 271.64, 141.6 ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
              [141.6 , 141.6 , 271.64,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
              [  0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  , 105.18,   0.  ,   0.  ],
              [  0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  , 105.18,   0.  ],
              [  0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  , 105.18]])
C_prime_sum = 0

CC = ElasticTensor(ElasticTensor.from_voigt(C))
for idx, op in enumerate(ops_rotation_list):
         # perform the 4th order tensor rotation.
        C_prime = ElasticTensor(
            np.einsum('im,jn,mnop,ok,pl', op, op, CC, op.T, op.T), tol=1e-5)
        C_prime_sum += C_prime
C_prime = C_prime_sum / (idx + 1)
A=C_prime.voigt
```

#### Output

```
print(A) yields the below values which is equal to C:

array([[271.64, 141.6 , 141.6 ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [141.6 , 271.64, 141.6 ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [141.6 , 141.6 , 271.64,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [  0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  , 105.18,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [  0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  , 105.18,   0.  ],
       [  0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  , 105.18]])
```